# Sublime Text3-Autolint setup

Tags: sublimetext3

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTOew.png)

Hey guys, I am new to Sublime Text3, and last week somehow I changed the way ST3 lint my code and show the error information. It looks actually a little annoying and I would like to get rid of these instant error display while I am coding. Can someone tell me how to do that?

In addition, how to setup ST3 so that when you type a function from a package, it could show its meaning and format? I can do it in my Windows PC but failed in MAC.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Open your package control, for Ubuntu its `Ctrl+Shift+P`, It may be `Cmd+Shift+P`, type disable in the package, it would show you `Package Control:: Disable Package`, press an enter key, now disable the packages that are causing it.